# Why is jQuery submit triggering its own page when action is set to other page

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, asp-classic

I have below form in settings.asp page, that should submit to sendmail.asp, but when clicking the button I can see in console that it is triggering settings.asp instead, and I cannot figure out why, since the id on both form and button are unique.

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

*The below code is running in a ASP Classic loop

```html
<form name="MarkErrorReportSolved" id="MarkErrorReportSolved<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" action="sendmail/sendmail.asp?ErrorReportMarked=yes" method="post">

    <!-- Hidden inputs nessesary for send mail - START -->
    <input name="redirect" type="hidden" id="redirect<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=strReportIssueFullUrlNoQueryString%>?ErrorReportMarked=yes&ChangeDate=<%=objErrorReportNew("ChangeDate")%>&RepoerterName=<%=objErrorReportNew("RepoerterName")%>&AnchorPoint=ErrorReports">
    <input name="mailto" type="hidden" id="mailto<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=objErrorReportNew("Email")%>">
    <input name="MailCC" type="hidden" id="MailCC<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=Session("ADMail")%>">
    <input name="subject" type="hidden" id="subjec<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="Fejl rapporteret på EFP [LØST]">
    <input name="template" type="hidden" id="template<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="templates/emailtemplate_report_issue_solved.htm">
    <input name="html" type="hidden" id="html<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="yes">
    <input name="EFPVersion" type="hidden" id="EFPVersion<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=Session("EFPVersion")%>">
    <input name="EFPYear" type="hidden" id="EFPYear<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%= year(now) %>">
    <input name="HeaderSubHeadline" type="hidden" id="HeaderSubHeadline<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="Fejl Løst..">
    <input name="HeaderRightTop" type="hidden" id="HeaderRightTop<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="">
    <input name="HeaderRightBottom" type="hidden" id="HeaderRightBottom<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="">             


  <!-- Hidden inputs nessesary for send mail - END -->

  <!-- Hidden inputs extra for send mail - START -->

    <%
    ReportIssueSolvedsendername=objErrorReportNew("RepoerterName")
    ReportIssueSolvedFirstName = Split(ReportIssueSolvedsendername, " ")(0)
    %>

    <input name="ADdisplayName" type="hidden" id="ADdisplayName<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=Session("ADdisplayName")%>">
    <input name="ErrorDescription" type="hidden" id="ErrorDescription<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=objErrorReportNew("ErrorDescription")%>">
    <input name="EFPArea" type="hidden" id="EFPArea<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=objErrorReportNew("EFPArea")%>">
    <input name="ChangeDate" type="hidden" id="ChangeDate<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=objErrorReportNew("ChangeDate")%>">
    <input name="RepoerterName" type="hidden" id="RepoerterName<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=ReportIssueSolvedFirstName%>">
    <input name="ID" type="hidden" id="ID<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" value="<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>">

  <!-- Hidden inputs extra for send mail - END -->

  <button type="submit" form="MarkErrorReportSolved<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" title="Klik her for at markere fejl som løst<br><i>(Sender også mail til indsender)</i>" id="btnFetch<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>" class="btn btn-success mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></button></td>

  <script>
      
          $("#btnFetch<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>").click(function() {
              console.log("Button Clicked")
              // disable button
              $(this).prop("disabled", true);
              // add spinner to button
              $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
              $("#MarkErrorReportSolved<%=objErrorReportNew("ID")%>").submit();
              console.log("Form Submitted")
          });
      
  </script>  

</form>
```

Comment: There’s a lot of code there but the `action` appears to set correctly on the `form` so only thing I can think of is there is some other javascript that is being called that is changing the forms action attribute.

Comment: @user692942 that is a very good point, I will try investigating that :-)

Comment: @user692942 I found the issue .. I had a script at the bottom of the settings.asp ..`$('html').on('submit', 'form', function(e) { e.preventDefault()` .. with an $.ajax({ type: "POST" .. so you where absolutely right, there was a script on the page that prevented the submit .. THANK you for pointing me in that direction :-) .. Please post an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to Classic ASP as that code executes server-side and it’s clear from the code you have posted that the `form` has the correct `action` attribute set. It would also be clear from debugging via dev tools that the page submission is being redirected.

This means if you are getting a different page when submitting the form via code there must be some other script in the page that is modifying the `action` attribute of the form before the submission or is completely overriding it (i.e an AJAX request event handler etc).